# How to get the type holded by a generic

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Suppose i have this:

```
TClassAncestor = class;

TAbstractGeneric = class;

TGenericContainer<T : TClassAncestor, constructor> = class(TAbstractGeneric);

THoldedClass = class(TClassAncestor);

TMyClass = class(TClassAncestor)
strict private
   FExample : TGenericContainer<THoldedClass>;
end;
```

what i want here is a way to retrieve the type contained in the class field `FExample` so in this case it would be `THoldedClass` using the `RTTI`.

so far i got to this point:

```
procedure TryToExtract();
var 
  ARTTI : TRttiType;
  AField : TRttiField;
  ATypeData : PTypeData;
begin
  ARTTI := TRttiContext.Create().GetType(TMyClass);
  for AField in ARTTI.GetFields do
    if(AField.FieldType.TypeKind = tkClass) and (AField.Visibility = mvPrivate) then
      begin
        ATypeData := GetTypeData(AField.FieldType.Handle);
        if(ATypeData^.ClassType.InheritsFrom(TAbstractGeneric)) then
          begin
            //...
          end;
      end;
end;
```

i don't know what do to after this point so i appreciate any help or suggestion.